# Import Images as planes sequence - Blender gives me 5 planes?

Tags: animation, import, image

Importing 'Images as planes' (547 .PNGs with transparency).

For some reason, when I use the same settings as usual, Blender is creating 5 planes:
Images 1-35, 36-241, 242-437, 428-531 & 532-547.

Seems a bit random!

I can swap them in & out, sure, but does anyone know if this is a known bug, or I'm doing something wrong?

(Win 10, 16GB Ram. Blender 2.93.5. Working fine with a previous 384 image sequence. Task manager reporting Blender using 600MB after import. Each image 5MB, sequentially numbered from 1, all the same size files, 2.7GB total)

Comment: Just a quick note: when you say it did work with a previous 384 image sequence I assume it's a different sequence. Have you tried just importing 384 or less images of the new 547 images sequence? Sorry I can't test this myself I have no sequence that large at the moment.

Comment: the import will use the names and a number. For instance, "a1.jpg", "a2.jpg", "b1.jpg", "b2.jpg" will generate 2 sequences (because a and b are different prefixes).

Comment: Gordon - checking, the 384 images are only 1.4MB each. If I try importing just 384 of my 547 x 5MB images, I get the sequence divided into 3 planes: 1-35, 36-241 & 242-384. So the breaks are the same.. Lemon - the images are jjfa000.png, jjfa0002.png ->. jjfa0384.png; I can't see any reason why the sequence numbering would trigger a new plane in this instance.

Comment: (Sorry, typo, I meant jjfa0001.png)

Comment: it is translated into blender's standard image sequences, so that follows their rules.

Comment: Trying the same sequence but smaller images (1.4MB each, the same size as in my 384 image example that imports as a single plane), Blender cuts my sequence into only 2 planes, 1-450, 451-end, which is more manageable. If I'd done this first, we'd be speculating about a 630MB import limit per plane, but cutting at 35, then after another frames, then 195, then 103; it all seems so arbitrary.